# GCP: Producer Portal : Test Deployment during creating Product fails with "One or more licenses are unhealthy."

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machines, gcp

I am creating a new product in Producer Portal following the steps in [VM Creation](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/partners/vm)

I am using Deployment Manager as the way to deploy the package. On Validate step, the test deployment fails with this error. I havent added **virtual-disk-import**(`projects/compute-image-tools/global/licenses/virtual-disk-import`) license as a part of my base image creation.

Any idea how this gets added and is there a way to delete this license which gets added automatically during base image creation.
We had not faced the same issue when we did the same steps 2 years ago. Is this something that is newly introduced by Google?

[image: License added in the image details]

```
{
  "taskReports": [
    {
      "taskType": "CHECK_LICENSE_INFO",
      "createTime": "2023-09-08T14:25:37.614Z",
      "taskExecutionStatus": "ISSUES_FOUND",
      "digest": "One or more licenses are unhealthy.",
      "errorMessage": "Licenses: projects/compute-image-tools/global/licenses/virtual-disk-import found in the deployment manifest. These licenses are not owned by this Listing and should not be attached to any GCE disks in the deployment"
    }
  ]
```